# How to prove this theory I found out? Quicker way of doing 2's complement(finding out the value of a negative binary)

Tags: binary, numbers, theory, complement

I was playing around with 2's complement and found a quicker way of finding the value of a negative binary. Please help me prove this(right or wrong) or why it works! Thanks in advance!

2's complement is very useful for finding the value of a binary, however I thought of a much more concise way of solving such a problem(never seen anyone else publish it):

take a binary, for example: 1101 which is [assuming that space "1" is the sign] equal to **-3**.

using 2's complement we would do this...flip 1101 to 0010...add 0001 + 0010 ===> gives us 0011. 0011 in positive binary = 3. therefore 1101 = **-3**!

***What I realized:***

instead of all the flipping and adding, you can just do the basic method for solving for a positive binary(lets say 0101) is (2<sup>3</sup> * 0) + (2<sup>2</sup> * 1) + (2<sup>1</sup> * 0) + (2<sup>0</sup> * 1) = 5.

**Do exactly the same concept with a negative!(with a small twist)**

take 1101, for example:

for the first number instead of 2<sup>3</sup> * 1 = **8** , do -(2<sup>3</sup> * 1) = **-8**.

then continue as usual, doing **-8** + (2<sup>2</sup> * 1) + (2<sup>1</sup> * 0) + (2<sup>0</sup> * 1) = **-3**

Note: this seemed to work for every test I did.

Thanks for looking. Also, if you haven't seen this before please let me know, I never seen this anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution seems to work for the tests which I did! Thanks for the quick solution to 2's complement, I will still test out some more difficult questions.